# Sorting based on individual columns of lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists in the following format.

```
b =  
   {'a': [1, 1, 1], 
    'c': [1, 0, 0], 
    'b': [1, 0, 1], 
    'e': [0, 0, 1], 
    'd': [0, 0, 0], 
    'g': [0, 1, 1], 
    'f': [0, 1, 0], 
    'h': [1, 1, 0]
   }
```

What I am looking to do is to sort the lists and display the dictionary based on the columns of the lists. The first column should be sorted, next the second column should be sorted with the third column in the last.

I want my list like this.

```
b =  
   {'d': [0, 0, 0], 
    'e': [0, 0, 1], 
    'f': [0, 1, 0], 
    'g': [0, 1, 1], 
    'c': [1, 0, 0], 
    'b': [1, 0, 1], 
    'h': [1, 1, 0], 
    'a': [1, 1, 1]
   }
```

I can do the sort of the first value of the list like this.

```
sorted(b.items(), key=lambda e:e[1][0])
```

and similarly do the second and the third. However, if I sort the first column, the second and third would not be sorted.

So, I did this.

```
sorted(b.items(), key=lambda e:e[1])
```

which gives me the right answer. But I am not sure how this is working.

Second, if I do,

```
sorted(b.values(), reverse=True, key=lambda e:e[0])
```

Here, it sorts only the first column of the values while the rest two columns are not sorted.

I have my answer, but I am looking for explanations of this is working for some cases and does not work for others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, what are you sorting by and what output do you expect?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I explained that in my question, please read that. I am trying to sort the lists in the dictionary.

Comment: You are sorting by the lists with `e[1]` which is each list/value, what do you not understand about that?

Comment: Which is the correct answer, can you put your desired output in the question?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have the correct answer. My question was if Python knew how to sort on the lists, why it would not do the same for `sorted(b.values(), reverse=True, key=lambda e:e[0])' but I have the answer here. Its sorting here only on the particular column however, with `sorted(b.items(), key=lambda e:e[1])' it looks at the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted(b.items(), key=lambda e:e[1])
```

works because the lambda is returning the whole lists, e.g. `[1, 1, 1]`, `[1, 0, 0]`. Python's default rule for sorting lists is exactly what you need, it will sort lists by the first 'column' or entry in the list, if two lists have the same first item, then they will be sorted by the second item, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
sorted(b.items(), key=lambda e:e[1])
```

Works because it uses the entirety of each list as the key for comparison.  Python knows how to "lexicographically" compare lists by default, meaning it compares the first element, then if those are equal it proceeds to the next element.  Just like sorting words alphabetically.